# View Dropped IP Addresses in Azure SQL Whitelist

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-server

Is there a way to query Azure SQL server logs to see when an IP address was dropped from a whitelist? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First enable Auditing on the Azure SQL Database:

[image]

[image]

Next Create Log Analytics workspace and try to query:

[image]

We could not get the IP which failed connecting to the Azure SQL database as of the date.
However,we can get the sum/count of Failed/Successful Connections:

[image]